# MacBook not turning on (fan loop)

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, charging

I'm in a very frustrating situation of having my MacBook Pro 15' Retina (A1398) stuck in a boot loop. Well, not exactly boot loop: when I connect my MagSafe charger, it goes in a constant cycle of starting up fans and turning off, with a period as long as 1 second (or even less). I tried resetting SMC and NVRAM so far, but had no result apart from having my charger's led turn green from amber (temporary; only when I hold *Shift-Control-Option* combination). What could be the possible issues?

*I'll be getting it to a diagnostics facility (non-Apple) in a few days, it would help clarifying whether I could be lied to or not (considering the fact it's unofficial).*

Answer (score 1):

How is your backup Situation?, if you've got everything backed up, I recommend that you simply format your Drive and reinstall OS X. if you know how, and have the original Disk. If you don't let me know. -quick pointers-

-Insert reinstall CD in your mac.
-restart mac holding option.
-choose from the two drives the Reins-CD
-Boot into it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check this out: http://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/. The information you provide could correspond to a Retina Early 2013 model, which is affected.